# How to save an arrayList<LatLng> with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I was looking for this - but found only how to save an arrayList for example this code:

```
 Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(MyObject);
 prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

I want to store this object(point) which is LatLng in SharedPreferences, after that i will need to get it from this save. Here is what i want to save:

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
    **checkPoints.add(point);**
}
```

Comment: [Complex Preferences](https://github.com/fsilvestremorais/android-complex-preferences) can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using preferences you can use Sqlite database. But if you insist on using SharedPreferences then I don't think you have much choice as you can only store boolean, float, int, long, String or StringSet. The only possible way I see is that you concatenate all of the values with your own separator like

```
1123.4456:1234.223|1123.4456:1234.1233|1123.4456:1234.223|1123.4456:1234.223
```

and then just parse when retrieving it.

Comment: So I cannot put my type of object in SharedPreferences and I need to parse it on latitude and longitude

Comment: As I mentioned, you are only limited with a few data types when storing in the SharedPreferences. You can be creative by formatting a String yourself as I mentioned in my answer or convert it to a Json String and store it. But if you see that the data you are storing could grow in the future, then I strongly suggest to use Sqlite instead. Or use a 3rd party library suggested by Paresh Mayani